# Does the possibility of hell render procreation unethical?

Tags: quran

Due to the possibility of hell is it wrong to have children. Think about it if hypothetically you or I go to hell even for one second wouldn’t have been better if our mothers never birthed us. https://www.minds.com/newsfeed/1110017504393457664

Comment: It matters not what you are born but who you grow up to be  ~Albus Dumbledore

Answer (score 1):

The conclusive Islamic answer is that it is definitely not unethical.

In fact, it is encouraged and a good action to have children because the Prophet (SAW) said:

> "Marry, for I will boast of your great numbers." ([Sunan Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1261810))

The possibility of Hell does not make it unethical.

Answer (score 1):

In Islam If Allah wants a soul to enter this world, He will be born one way or another.

> Indeed, all things We created with predestination.

Quran (54:49)

**So even if you don't have child it doesn't mean he will not exist**. He might born in other family. If the child's destination is hell he will go there in one way or another.
But we don't know that.

By not having child you are just missing all the good deeds you could've gain through taking care of him.

Answer (score 0):

You choose your destination.  Your mother can try to guide you, but there is no force.  You cannot force love or other matters of the heart.

Answer (score 0):

It were atheists who tried to do it claiming we can't force someone to be in this world.  We muslims make children so that they can be paradise and if they disobey their lord then they deserve to be in hellfire.  If one makes sins but also repents, Allah's mercy is sort.  Allah is most merciful, the thing is if one is careless he will go the hell fire.

Answer (score 0):

Muslims are to live with one foot in this world and the other, in the other world; there is no monaticism in Islam; and not is there a rule on celibacy.

Hence, it is **not** haram to have children.

The possibility of hell is to make men reflect on the nature of good and evil and the choices before them; and not to deliberately refrain from living.